# In hashmap what is the meaning of hm.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34));

Tags: java, jsp, collections, hashmap

My serious doubt here is that, why are we using new Double(3434.34)? can we use hm.put("Zara", 3434.34) directly instead of hm.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34)? most of the beginners may have this doubt, I am just raising it. please dont feel odd, if it looks kiddish...any clarification on this would definitely help newbies like me..

Comment: Yes you can do that(Java 1.5 or later). The value will auto-boxed to Double type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store primitive values directly in a `Hashmap` - the keys and values must be subclasses of `Object`.

Prior to JDK 1.5 (aka 5.0), the `new Double()` syntax was required to wrap the primitive value and store it.

In later versions "auto boxing" will allow you to write `.put("Zara", 3434.34)` and automagically invoke `new Double` on the primitive.

Answer (score 5):

We can, now.

Older versions of Java don't auto-box/auto-unbox primitives and their Object counterparts, so this might be either code written for an older version of Java, or written by someone who "grew up" with older versions of Java and never learned about the syntax improvements that landed in 1.5 and later.

Answer (score 0):

to minimize your question, you could make assignments to ''Object'' and check the class+value:

```
Object autoboxed = 3434.34;
Object explicit = new Double(3434.34);
System.out.println("auto-boxed:"+autoboxed.getClass());
System.out.println("explicit:"+explicit.getClass());
```